# Magento email templates "Error in template processing"

Tags: magento-1.9.1

I'm pulling my hair out with this one so hopefully someone can help.

I upgraded my "**Mage_All_Latest**" package to the latest one (1.9.1.0) and since then my transactional emails don't seem to have any styles. The ones that I've created myself under `System->Transactional Emails` are working but the standard ones just don't work. Below is what I get when I preview, this is also how it is received when sent (it still contains the order details however, just no header/footer or style):

```
{Error in template processing} {{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}
Thank you for your order from .
Once your package ships we will send an email with a link to track your order. Your order summary is below. Thank you again for your business.
Order Questions?
Your order #
Placed on
Bill to:
Payment method:
{Error in template processing}
```

Thanks for any help advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you do an update via shell ./mage upgrade-all or reinstall via magento connect. It is possible that some packages where missing on your install or patches have been applied.

I had magento 1.9.0.1 with the same problem. I upgraded via shell to 1.9.1.0 and the email header/footer issue was fixed!

Once fixed, you should see options for Email Header Template, Email Footer Template and Non-inline CSS File(s) under Design > Transactional Emails.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once then i found it happened because i changed the Email template in local/... and the Magento changed the email template in the new version so  i copied my change to the new template and every thing went back to normal

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: i wanted to add it as comment but i couldn't as i have low reputation i couldn't any way i was getting the same error {Error in template processing} and by applying my changes to the new template it works fine